# How to pass url prop in Route's element

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How do we get to use url prop(and other props) in the new react-router version 6 and pass it to the element's component like we used to do in the render method?

react-router: V6

```
<Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>}/>
```

react-router: V5

```
<Route exact path="/ds/:id" render={(url) => <Header url={url}/> }/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The update has great [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview). It covers the changes pretty clearly. The short answer is just call `useParams()` inside the component. `const {url} = useParams()`. But, there are other changes you'll want to embrace - specifically using `<Outlet/>` with nested routes.

```
// in your router
<Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />}>
  <Route path=":invoiceId" element={<Invoice />} />
  <Route index element={
    <main className='p-4'>
      <p>Select an invoice</p>
    </main>
  } />
</Route>

//Invoice.tsx
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import { getInvoice } from "../data"

export default function Invoice() {
  let params = useParams()
  let invoice = getInvoice(parseInt(params.invoiceId as string, 10)) || { amount: 0, name: 'not found', due: 'n/a', number: 0 }
  return (
    <main className="p-4">
      <h2>Total Due: {invoice.amount}</h2>
      <p>
        {invoice.name}: {invoice.number}
      </p>
      <p>Due Date: {invoice.due}</p>
    </main>
  )
}
```